# How can I fill the attributes of a class (which are functions), then call on a function of that class without re-running all the attribute functions?

Tags: python, class

I have the following class:

```
class AnalyseMyHandOnFlop():

    def __init__(self, stack_tracker, SPR_tracker, guy_to_right_bet_size):
        self.top_set = self.top_set_checker()
        self.flopped_top_set_flop1 = self.top_set[0]
        self.flopped_top_set_flop2 = self.top_set[1]

        self.nut_flush = self.some_flush_check()
        self.flopped_flush_flop1 = self.nut_flush[0]
        self.flopped_flush_flop2 = self.nut_flush[1]
        ...

    def some_function_I_call_after(self): 
        if self.flopped_flush_flop2:
            <do_something> 
        elif self.flopped_top_set_flop1:
            <do_something>
```

Because timing is crucial in the execution of the script, I would like to execute `AnalyseMyHandOnFlop()`, and fill all of its attributes (which are function calls).

Then after some other processing, I would like to call solely on `some_function_I_call_after`, without re-running the entire class `AnalyseMyHandOnFlop()` and it's functions again, because initialising this class and its function calls takes a long time.

Is this possible?

To add some context, at the moment I am running `AnalyseMyHandOnFlop()` then immediately calling `self.some_function_I_call_after()`.
But I would like to run `AnalyseMyHandOnFlop()` first and fill all of its attributes, then after some other processing, I would like to call on JUST `self.some_function_I_call_after()` (without reinitialising the `AnalyseMyHandOnFlop()` class as this takes a long time). Also, notice that the function `self.some_function_I_call_after()` references the attributes values `self.flopped_flush_flop2` and `self.flopped_flush_flop1`.

Comment: Did you tried to make this function "some_function_I_call_after" separated from class and make class only as holder for instance attribute? This will give you an opportunity to cache the class and use it's instance in function when you need. Example of usage 
af = AnalyseMyHandOnFlop     
def some_function_I_call_after(some_obj: obj): 
        if some_obj.flopped_flush_flop2:
            <do_something> 
        elif some_obj.flopped_top_set_flop1:
            <do_something>
some_function_I_call_after(af)

Comment: How is `self` ready to call `top_set_checker` if it hasn't been initialized yet? Is it really a class or static method? I would rethink the design of this class.

Comment: `__init__` isn't currently using any of its arguments, and it's not clear what `top_set_checker` and `some_flush_check` are doing. The values you are assigning to the attributes in `__init__` should be arguments; how you *generate* those arguments is the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it is possible.

```
# initialize the hand
hand = AnalyseMyHandOnFlop(...)

# do lots of other stuff

# now call the function
hand.some_function_I_call_after()
```

Frankly, this is so basic that I think I may have misunderstood your question...

Comment: Okay, I fundamentally misunderstood something. Thanks for the clarification